# hive server 2- Exception hive.service.ServiceException: Error setting stage directories

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh

Below Error came while restarting hive service2 of cloudera cdh5.2.
I am getting below error while starting hiveservice2 in cloudera cdh5.2.
This exception is rare. There is also a jira item opened for this issue

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8606

```
  Error starting services HiveServer2
    org.apache.hive.service.ServiceException: Error setting stage directories
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.start(CLIService.java:132)
        at org.apache.hive.service.CompositeService.start(CompositeService.java:70)
        at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.start(HiveServer2.java:73)
        at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.startHiveServer2(HiveServer2.java:101)
        at org.apache.hive.service.server.HiveServer2.main(HiveServer2.java:149)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkOwner(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOwner(FSNamesystem.java:6151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermissionInt(FSNamesystem.java:1678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermission(FSNamesystem.java:1658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setPermission(NameNodeRpcServer.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.setPermission(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setPermission(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setPermission(DFSClient.java:2263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$23.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$23.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.setPermission(DistributedFileSystem.java:1243)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.setupStagingDir(CLIService.java:500)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.start(CLIService.java:128)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkOwner(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:169)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:157)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6250)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6232)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkOwner(FSNamesystem.java:6151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermissionInt(FSNamesystem.java:1678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.setPermission(FSNamesystem.java:1658)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.setPermission(NameNodeRpcServer.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.setPermission(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:148)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.setPermission(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:587)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1026)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2013)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2009)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2007)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:206)
        at $Proxy17.setPermission(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.setPermission(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:337)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at $Proxy18.setPermission (Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.setPermission(DFSClient.java:2261)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted /user/hive/.staging directory from hdfs file system.
Also deleted some of the /tmp/hive-hive and /tmp/hive-root files from hdfs.
It solved the problem, but I am not aware of the root cause. If any one is having better solution , its most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: I would expect that an abnormal shutdown (like unplug) could cause the orphanage

Comment: yeah that could be the issue .